# Remove everything from before the :

Tags: python

I need to remove everything before the `:`

`Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks`

I just need to keep the `Scanning IP Blocks`

```
val = "Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks"

pos = val.rfind(':')
if pos >= 0:
    val = val[:pos]

print(val)
```

But I'm getting the everything before the `:`

Comment: Use `val = val[pos+1:]` instead. If you don't want the blank right after `:`, put `.lstrip()` afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> import re
>>> val = "Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks"
>>> re.sub(r'^.*?:', '', val)
' Scanning IP Blocks'
```

Answer (score 1):

`[:pos]` means `0` to `pos` which you don't want. write `[pos+1:]` what will give you `pos` to the end of the string.

```
val = "Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks"

pos = val.rfind(':')
if pos >= 0:
    val = val[pos+1:]

print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for string indexing is `string[startIndex:endIndex]`. You can use:

```
val = "Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks"

pos = val.rfind(':')
if pos >= 0:
    val = val[pos+1:]

print(val)
```

or you can use `split()`:

```
val = "Active Scanning: Scanning IP Blocks"

pos = val.rfind(':')
if pos >= 0:
    val = val.split(":")[1]

print(val)
```